# Where does $(\tan x)^{\sin x}=(\cot x)^{\cos x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

So I was yet again searching throughout the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/Bg1pJb3aMiA) video by SyberMath that asked the question:

$$\text{Solve: }~~~(\tan x)^{\sin x}=(\cot x)^{\cos x}$$

Which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving it:

---

$$(\tan x)^{\sin x}=(\cot x)^{\cos x}$$

---

$$\sin(x)\ln(\tan x)=\cos(x)\ln(\cot x)$$

---

$$\tan(x)\ln(\tan x)=\ln(\cot x)~~~~~~~\text{ (since }\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)\text{)}$$

---

$$\text{Therefore, we need to find where }(\tan x)^{\tan x}\text{ is equal to }\cot(x)$$

---

$$\text{And solving for }x\text{ will get us that }x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n,n\in\mathbb{Z}\text{, (}\mathbb{Z}\text{ being the set of integers)}$$

---

And, plugging this into Desmos we see that we are correct!

[image]

---

$$\mathbf{\text{My question}}$$

---

Is my solution correct, or is there anything that I could do to attain the correct solution more easily?

Comment: $(tanx)^{(sinx+cosx)} =1$ implies that either $tanx=1$ or $sinx+cosx=0$

Comment: Be careful: the equation becomes meaningless if $\tan x \le 0$. Under that assumption you can argue as @ShlokJain comment suggests, and the fact that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ must have the same sign, you can discard the condition $\sin x + \cos x =0$. This means that the equation is equivalent to $\tan x =1$.

Comment: @Crostul So the equation could only be possibly true if $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n,n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: At $(\tan x) (\ln \tan x) = \ln \cot x$ note that $\cot x = (\tan x)^{-1}$ and $\ln \cot x = -\ln\tan x.$   So, $(\tan x)(\ln\tan x) = -\ln \tan x.$  Either, $\tan x = -1$ or $\ln \tan x = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\tan x)^{\sin x}=(\cot x)^{\cos x}$ and $\cot x=\frac{1}{\tan x}$, we get

$$(\tan x)^{\sin x}=(\tan x)^{-\cos x}\Rightarrow (\tan x)^{\sin x+\cos x}=1$$

Case.(1) $$\tan x=1\Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}4+n\pi, ~~n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Case.(2）$$\sin x+\cos x=0\Rightarrow \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)=0\Rightarrow x=-\frac{\pi}4+n\pi, ~~n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

The solution is:

$$ x=\pm\frac{\pi}4+n\pi, ~~n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Just an observation that the answer can be written as $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}n=\frac{\pi}{4}(2n+1)$

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of brevity, let $s = \sin x$ and $c = \cos x$.  Then $\tan x = \frac{s}{c}$ and $\cot x = \frac{c}{s}$, so:

$$(\frac{s}{c})^s=(\frac{c}{s})^{c}$$

Taking the logarithm of each side gives:

$$s(\ln s - \ln c)=c(\ln c - \ln s)$$

Which can be rearranged to:

$$(s + c)(\ln s - \ln c) = 0$$

If $s + c = 0$, i.e., $\sin x + \cos x = 0$, then $x \in \{ \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4} \} + 2\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If $\ln s - \ln c = 0$, then $\sin x = \cos x$, so $x \in \{ \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4} \} + 2\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Combining these cases gives $x \in \{ \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4} \} + 2\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In other words, $x$ can be any *odd* multiple of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

$$\boxed{x = \frac{\pi}{4}(2n+1), n \in \mathbb{Z}}$$

Comment: Great answer! I think that the two answers here are the only ways we can actually solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant of the method given by Dan, again letting $s = \sin x, c = \cos x$, we have:

$$\left( \frac s c \right)^s = \left( \frac c s \right)^c \iff \frac{s^s}{c^s} = \frac{c^c}{s^c} \iff s^{s+c} = c^{s+c}$$

Rather than taking the logarithm, we've simply cross-multiplied. $a^n = b^n \iff a=b \lor n=0$. (That is, this is true when the base is the same on both sides, or when both exponentials are $1$.) This corresponds to $\sin x = \pm \cos x$, which is true at all *odd* multiples of $\tau/8$, as shown by others.

Comment: Ah, I see you're a Tauist.